# JQGrid context menu for each cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu, row, cell

I use context menu to allow user do different actions on cell in JQGrid:

```
function showContextMenu(rowId)
{
    menu1 = [ {'View':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked View!"); } },
              $.contextMenu.separator, 
              {'Upload':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Upload!"); }},
                $.contextMenu.separator,
                {'Remove':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Remove!"); }}
               ];


    $('#' + rowId).contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
```

Event

```
onRightClickRow : function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){
     showContextMenu(rowid,iCol);
}
```

It works, but clumsy: problem that it needs to do double right click - because on first click (if I have understand correct) - bind function and only on second - display menu.
I have try to use

```
gridComplete : function {
 var dataIds = $('#list').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i = 0;i < dataIds.length; i++) {
showContextMenu(dataIds[i]);
 }
```

But in this case I cannot receive iCol. What solution can be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify values ​​for the rows and cells.

```
var dataIds = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
 var countCols = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames').length;
 for (var i = 0;i < dataIds.length ; i++) {
    for (j=0;j<= countCols;j++)
       showContextMenu(dataIds[i],i+1,j);
 }
```

And change the function

```
function showContextMenu(rowid,iRow,iCol){
        menu1 = [ {'Yahoooo!':function(menuItem,menu) { 
        alert(rowid+" — "+iRow+" — "+iCol);
        } }];
jQuery("tr#"+rowid+" td").eq(iCol).contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'osx'});};
```